# What is the use case of Firebase Queue?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing some experiments on Firebase realtime database. Though I came across firebase-queue. This is what docs says https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue.

> A fault-tolerant, multi-worker, multi-stage job pipeline built on the Firebase Realtime Database.

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firebase-queue lets you use Realtime Database to submit jobs to a backend server you control.  Clients write into the database, and that data is received by firebase-queue, where you can do whatever you want with it.

If you have interest in running backend code that reacts to changes in your Firebase project, you are much better off looking into [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), because you won't have to manage a backend server at all.   You just write and deploy code to it.

Comment: Thanks! I believe it was used when `Firebase` cloud function was not there. As now you can use cloud function to process something as well as schedule cron jobs also. Do you think `firebase-queue` has still any use case ?

Comment: If you need a special machine setup or environment that you control to help do your work, you might still want to use firebase-queue.  It's hard to predict what that might be.